Seg fault on string array items after tokenizing in external function
I am trying to build a runtime command line tool and don't get why I get a segmentation fault when I try to tokenize the string input by the user.
In the str_utils.c file, the expression printf("token: %s\n", tokens[i]); is evaluated properly and the content of the array printed, but in the user_input.c file, if I print the pointer with %p, everything is fine, but as soon as try to print with %s, I get a segmentation fault. So it looks like I am failing at storing the individual token in the array tokens.
Here is the code:
// str_utils.c

int str_utils_split(char *str, char *delimiter, char **tokens,
                    int *tokens_count) {

  char *local_str = strdup(str);

  for (char *token = strtok(local_str, delimiter); token != NULL;
       token = strtok(NULL, delimiter)) {

    tokens = realloc(tokens, sizeof(char *) * (++(*tokens_count)));

    if (tokens == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "realloc failed! Exiting!");
      return 1;
    }

    /* Am doing something wrong here? I ended up doing this because
       I read strtok was not doing any allocation
    */
    tokens[*tokens_count - 1] =
        strcpy((char *)calloc(strlen(token) + 1, sizeof(char)), token);
  }

  // or there?
  tokens = realloc(tokens, sizeof(char *) * (*tokens_count + 1));
  tokens[*tokens_count + 1] = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < *tokens_count; i++) {
    printf("tokenin called fn: %s\n", tokens[i]);
  }

  free(local_str);

  return 0;
}

// user_input.c

char command_line_buffer[100];

void ui_parse_command(char *line, ui_command_t *command_obj) {

  char **cmd_tokens = malloc(sizeof(char *));
  char *delimiter = " ";
  int tokens_count = 0;

  str_utils_split(line, delimiter, cmd_tokens, &tokens_count);
  
  for (int i = 0; i < tokens_count; i++) {
    printf("token in calling fn: %p\n", cmd_tokens[i]); // OK
    printf("token in calling fn: %s\n", cmd_tokens[i]); // seg fault
  }
}

void ui_start_prompt(void (*callback)(ui_command_t *)) {

  printf("auralizer> ");
  ui_command_t command_obj;

  while (fgets(command_line_buffer, sizeof(command_line_buffer), stdin) !=
         NULL) {

    ui_parse_command(command_line_buffer, &command_obj);
    callback(&command_obj);
    printf("auralizer> ");
  }
}

I tried with and without local copies, with and without a local tmp_tokens array in the split function, I tried to start from a NULL pointer in user_input.c, I turned it in all directions and it always compiles, but always goes into a segfault at the same place.
The correct output would be (the correct output just happened once and crashed again after I restarted the program):
auralizer> tralala lala
token in called fn: tralala
token in called fn: lala

token in calling fn: tralala
token in calling fn: lala

And after re-executing the program (printf("%s")):
auralizer> tralala lala
token in called fn: tralala
token in called fn: lala

[1]    27102 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./bin/auralizer

Printing the pointers (printf("%p")):
auralizer> tralala lala
token in called fn: tralala
token in called fn: lala

token in calling fn: 0x557717df4cb0
token in calling fn: 0x557717df4cd0


Remember that in C argument to functions are passed by value. That means the value used in the call to the function is copied into the local argument variable of the function. When you modify the local argument variable, you only modify the local argument variable, not the original value. Please think about that and what happens with cmd_tokens when you call str_utils_split.

tokens[*tokens_count + 1] = 0;

strdup allocate and copies, but you never free the memory

you should always check return value of realloc

On a different note, if realloc fails then it will return a NULL pointer but leave the original memory unaffected. That means if you call tokens = realloc(tokens, ...) and it fails, you will loose the original pointer and have a memory leak.

Also, if you don't build with extra warnings enabled, you should do that. And treat them as errors. And if your compiler support it, build with a sanitizer (for GCC or Clang, add -g -fsanitize=address,undefined) and the error should be caught and perhaps possible to debug. As would using a debugger and step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values. Then you would see that cmd_tokens will not be equal to tokens when the function returns.

@Someprogrammerdude I pass the pointer by value, then realloc in a loop and for each token, I allocate memory, copy this token into this memory and "attach" it to the local char** array, leaving the original array  cmd_tokens intact? It has been modified because I can see the pointers in the last print no?
Do the strings live only locally? They do not, right? As I allocated memory for them? (please correct me if I'm wrong)

You need to pass the pointer by reference, i.e. a pointer to the pointer. That is you need to pass a char *** type, using &cmd_tokens. And (*tokens) when you access it in the function. This is just the same as you already do for tokens_count. Didn't it strike you as odd that you need to do it for one argument that you modify inside the function, but not the other?

Ok you were both super fast at writing :)
Let me please check all that! Thanks!

@Someprogrammerdude yes it did strike me as odd... But I was like: meh... :D
I should have been booh!

That means you have good instincts... Listen to them!  :)

So it looks like the array is now correctly updated (don' t know why... :D). I just updated my Makefile with the options added a check after the last realloc! Thank you for that as well :)
I get a segmentation fault if I don't have exactly one space :D
But this is an other story. I will just check the indexes. That's not a big issue. Probably what @AndersK just pointed out. I changed so many things while trying to understand what was happening, that I lost track a bit...
The idea about "arrays are pointers" have messed my brain up a bit. But I understand now. Thank you so much!

I can't upvote yet, so I'll send you love instead.

Ok all correct now (I missed the parenthesis around tokens in (*tokens)[*tokens_count]). I am a punishment :D

Should I post the corrected code? It's not that important I guess... Anyway I thank you both very much for your time and help!

If you have fixed the issue, you should post an answer. It may be useful to someone else experiencing similar issues.

Ok @Chris! Done!

A few style notes.
Using strdup
To me this is suspect:

    tokens[*tokens_count - 1] =
        strcpy((char *)calloc(strlen(token) + 1, sizeof(char)), token);



You don't need to cast the result of calloc. Relevant reading: Should I cast the result of malloc (in C)?
You don't check that calloc succeeded.
You've already used strdup once. Why not here?

    tokens[*tokens_count - 1] = strdup(token);

Offloading the resizeable array logic
You've added a lot of complexity to your code to manage a growing dynamic array. You could simply work with a fixed size array and pass a maximum size parameter to your tokenizing function, avoiding this issue entirely, or you could develop a data type and accompanying functions to handle a growing dynamic array (or "vector") so that you don't need to mingle that logic with the tokenizing logic. This will aid in debugging.
Note that growing such a data structure by a single element is inefficient and involves many more realloc calls, which are comparatively expensive. Better to grow by a factor of 2 or 1.5. The optimum growth factor is a subject of debate and veers heavily into opinion territory. You would likely also want sv_make_empty to start a vector with a capacity of more than 1.
Such an approach might look like the following, where the tokenizing logic is simply in main.
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct StringVec {
    size_t cap;
    size_t sz;
    char **data;
} StringVec;

StringVec *sv_make_empty(void);
StringVec *sv_grow(StringVec *);
StringVec *sv_push(StringVec *, char *);
void sv_destroy(StringVec *);

int main(void) {
    char line[] = "Hello world foo  bar";
    char *delim = " ";
    StringVec *vec = sv_make_empty();

    if (!vec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Allocation of string vector failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char *tok = strtok(line, delim);
    while (tok) {
        if (!sv_push(vec, strdup(tok))) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Pushing onto vector failed.\n");
            sv_destroy(vec);
            return 1;
        }

        tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec->sz; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", vec->data[i]);
    }

    sv_destroy(vec);
}

StringVec *sv_make_empty(void) {
    StringVec *vec = malloc(sizeof(*vec));
    if (!vec) return NULL;

    vec->cap = 1;
    vec->sz = 0;

    vec->data = malloc(vec->cap * sizeof(char *));
    if (!vec->data) {
        free(vec);
        return NULL;
    }

    return vec;
}

StringVec *sv_grow(StringVec *vec) {
    size_t growth_factor = 2;
    char **new_data = realloc(vec->data, vec->cap * growth_factor);
    if (!new_data) {
        return NULL;
    }

    vec->data = new_data;
    vec->cap *= growth_factor;

    return vec;
}

StringVec *sv_push(StringVec *vec, char *str) {
    if (!vec) return NULL;
    if (vec->sz == vec->cap && !sv_grow(vec)) return NULL;

    vec->data[vec->sz++] = str;

    return vec;
}

void sv_destroy(StringVec *vec) {
    if (!vec) return;

    free(vec->data);
    free(vec);
}

Extra space
Now with the vector growing the way it does, it's possible a function returning a StringVec is keeping more memory alive than need be. You can keep the memory under control without having to do the costly grow-by-one method by implementing a sv_shrink function.
StringVec *sv_shrink(StringVec *vec) {
    if (!vec) return NULL;
    if (vec->cap <= 1 || vec->cap == vec->sz) return vec;

    char **new_data = realloc(vec->data, sizeof(char *) * vec->sz);
    if (!new_data) return NULL;

    vec->data = new_data;
    vec->cap = vec->sz;

    return vec;
}

While passing a char *** argument also works, being a three star programmer is not a good thing.

Thanks so much for this! I chose this project (an auralizer) to get my hands dirty with C and am in the phase you are ashamed of when you read the code again a few years after :D Meaning your input showing the implementation of a vector is really helpful! Looks like I have to do some refactoring :). I'll have to implement a hashtable as well (not asking you for doing it :D).

Concerning the groth_factor you are totally right. In my case it would be for a very small string vector (which again makes the fixed length array better), but if you generalize with a struct then it matters :) I will change the calloc to strdup now. Thank you for everything :)

@dioptrical Chris' StringVec approach is (overall) the cleanest. It's similar to a c++ std::vector<char *>

@CraigEstey yes definitely! Look at the answer I wrote with the corrected code. I am mentioning exactly this!

Thank to @Someprogrammerdude and @AndersK, I could reajust my thoughts and correct the code. Please refer to the comments above.
Thanks again!
Here the corrected code with corrections in comments on previous line (please check @Chris' answer for a nicer way to execute this task):
// string_utils.c

// third parameter accepts now a pointer to a string array
int str_utils_split(char *str, char *delimiter, char ***tokens,
                    int *tokens_count) {

// adding checks for all allocations
  char *local_str = strdup(str);
  if (local_str == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "local string copy allocation failed");
    return 1;
  }

  for (char *token = strtok(local_str, delimiter); token != NULL;
       token = strtok(NULL, delimiter)) {
    char *allocated_token = NULL;

// tokens is now referred as a pointer *tokens instead of tokens
    *tokens = realloc(*tokens, sizeof(char *) * (++(*tokens_count)));
    if (*tokens == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "realloc failed! Exiting!");
      return 1;
    }

// [] has higher precedence than * we need parenthesis
    // (*tokens)[*tokens_count - 1] = strcpy((char *)calloc(strlen(token) + 1, sizeof(char)), token);
// correction after @Chris suggestion about strdup
    if ((allocated_token = strdup(token)) != NULL) {
      (*tokens)[*tokens_count - 1] = allocated_token;
    } else {
      fprintf(stderr, "token allocation failed!");
      return 1;
    }
  }

  *tokens = realloc(*tokens, sizeof(char *) * (*tokens_count + 1));

  if (*tokens == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "realloc failed! Exiting!");
    return 1;
  }

  (*tokens)[*tokens_count] = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < *tokens_count; i++) {
    printf("token in called fn: %s\n", (*tokens)[i]);
  }

  free(local_str);

  return 0;
}


// user_input.c

void ui_parse_command(char *command_line_buffer, ui_command_t *command_obj) {

  char **cmd_tokens = NULL;
  char *delimiter = " ";
  int tokens_count = 0;

// here we pass now cmd_tokens by reference (its address &)
  str_utils_split(command_line_buffer, delimiter, &cmd_tokens, &tokens_count);
  for (int i = 0; i < tokens_count; i++) {
    printf("token in calling fn: %s\n", cmd_tokens[i]);
// freeing added but of course only for the context of this snippet :D
    free(cmd_tokens[i]);
  }
  free(cmd_tokens);
}

void ui_start_prompt(void (*callback)(cmd_command_t *)) {

  printf("auralizer> ");
  cmd_command_t command_obj;

  while (fgets(command_line_buffer, sizeof(command_line_buffer), stdin) !=
         NULL) {

    ui_parse_command(command_line_buffer, &command_obj);
    callback(&command_obj);
    printf("auralizer> ");
  }
}


Thanks for the heads up under Chris' answer. AFAICT, your revised answer still has a triple star parameter. And, you're returning three values. A real return for the okay/error bool. But, still have two returned values. And, his answer uses a "capacity" member (which is good). So, now, 1 + 3 returned values. Anytime, I have a func that returns two(?) or more such values, I create a struct even if it's only used in 1-2 places (e.g.) struct funcret { int size; int cap; char **arr; int err; }; Then, a pointer to this can be [easily] passed around to multiple functions.

Oh ok. So have the return value as a member of the struct you return. So you stop the execution of the function returning and then check on the caller side the value of funcrect.err. That looks also neat :) thanks for the input. The code I posted is incomplete as I am not checking the function's return value anyway. And yes I won't leave the function as is in my code. I will refactor everything and implement Chris' logic and now yours as well :)
